# MS Access Query into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access-2010

I have a column [year] in *table*

```
year
2
4
7
4
2
```

and I want to transfer the MS Access query code

```
SELECT [year]<5 FROM table
```

into a code that works in SQL Server 2008 **and does not include a WHERE clause**. I want the criteria checking to be in the SELECT statement, just like it is in the MS Access code. Is this possible?

I can do it with CASE statements, but is there a shorter way?

(The reason for my wish to include the criteria in the SELECT statement is the complexity of the whole query.)

Comment: "I can do it with CASE statements" -> can you post what you have done.

Comment: `SELECT [year]<5 FROM table` does not select numbers less than 5, it selects a boolean, if the number is less than 5, true, otherwise, false. You need a where statement. If the query is too complex, simplify. Consider sub queries / sub tables.

Comment: Seems like I had a wrong understanding of the command.
I solved it by CASE statetments now, which works fine.

@Bharadwaj:
For example: SELECT (CASE WHEN year<2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM table